# BigQuery: Select REPEATED fields as REPEATED fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm loading data into BigQuery via Avro, one of my columns is an Array. That appears to load ok, however, because BigQuery appends root as a prefix to the column names, I need to select all the columns into their appropriate names. I have included the --noflatten_results flag but the query fails with "Cannot create valid output schema for field order_ids. Try renaming order_ids to root.order_ids in the outermost SELECT"

Query:

```
SELECT
root.a AS a,
root.b AS b,
root.orders_ids AS order_ids,
root.c AS c,
root.d AS d 
FROM dataset.table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing a parent record from a repeated field is difficult using legacy SQL.  `--noflatten_results` is best-effort and doesn't support many transformations over repeated fields, such as renaming.

If you use standard SQL, it should be fairly simple.  Results from standard SQL queries are unflattened by default, and referencing fields within records in a `SELECT` clause removes them from parent records.

```
SELECT root.* from dataset.table;
```

Using the CLI, you can specify to use standard SQL by adding `--nouse_legacy_sql` to your command line.

Related documentation:

- [How to enable standard SQL in UI/CLI/API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)
- [General docs for standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/)

Comment: Thanks Danny, this works. Have one follow up if you know. I was using TIMESTAMP to convert an epoch long into a human readable date, but that doesn't work in standard. Is there a way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I'm blind. Missed the "Additional timestamp conversion" functions in the docs. Thanks. Good to go now!